# R: Scraping the publish date of an specific website using RVest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

i'm currently webscraping in R using RVest.
My current website is "https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-2/Wohnung-Miete/Rheinland-Pfalz/Koblenz". 
But i don't manage to grab the individual pushlishDates of the estate offers.

F.e, this is an HTML-part i found embedded in the script.

"@publishDate":"2019-10-12T10:50:57.831+02:00"

I don't manage to find the proper RVest-Selector... The code below returns Character[0], as the node "publishDate" does not work.

What is the required html_node() to scrape each individual publishDate? Thanks a lot in advance.

```
library(rvest)

immo_webp <- read_html ("https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-2/Wohnung-Miete/Rheinland-Pfalz/Koblenz")

PDate <- immo_webp %>%
  html_nodes("publishDate") %>%
  html_text()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Content is dynamically loaded from a `script` tag. You can regex out the appropriate string and parse with `jsonlite` then extract into dataframe items of interest e.g. with `purrr`

---

**R:**

```
library(rvest)
library(stringr)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)

p <- read_html('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-2/Wohnung-Miete/Rheinland-Pfalz/Koblenz') %>% html_text()
data <- jsonlite::parse_json(str_match_all(p,'resultListModel: (.*\\})')[[1]][,2])
results <- data$searchResponseModel$resultlist.resultlist$resultlistEntries[[1]]$resultlistEntry

df <- map_df(results, function(item) {

  data.frame(property = item$resultlist.realEstate$address$description$text,
             datePublished = item$`@publishDate`,
             stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
})

View(df)
```

[image]

---

**Py:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests, re, json
import pandas as pd

r = requests.get('https://www.immobilienscout24.de/Suche/S-2/Wohnung-Miete/Rheinland-Pfalz/Koblenz')
p = re.compile(r'resultListModel: (.*})')
data = json.loads(p.findall(r.text)[0])
info = [
        (entry['resultlist.realEstate']['address']['description']['text']
        ,entry['@publishDate']) 
        for entry in data['searchResponseModel']['resultlist.resultlist']['resultlistEntries'][0]['resultlistEntry']
        ]
print(pd.DataFrame(info,columns = ['Property','PublishedDate']))
```